# Cannot select after class changed

Tags: jquery, selector

```
/* ========== Expand Left Menu ========== */
    $('div.minimized').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("minimized");
        $(this).addClass("expanded");
        $('a.main_nav').removeClass("min");
        $('a.main_nav').addClass("exp");
        $('#left_menu_ul li a').animate({"margin-left" : "-20px"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
        $('#expand_wrapper').animate({"width" : "270px"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
        $('#expand').animate({"left" : "227px"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
        $('#left_menu').animate({"width" : "270px"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
    });

    /* ========== Minimize Left Menu ========== */      
    $('div.expanded').click(function() {            
        $(this).removeClass("expanded");
        $(this).addClass("minimized");
        $('a.main_nav').removeClass("exp");
        $('a.main_nav').addClass("min");
        $('#expand_wrapper').removeAttr('style');
        $('#left_menu_ul li a').animate({"margin-left" : "-223px"}, 800, 'easeInExpo');
        $('#expand_wrapper').animate({"width" : "67px"}, 800, 'easeInExpo');
        $('#expand').animate({"left" : "26px"}, 800, 'easeInExpo');
        $('#left_menu').animate({"width" : "67px"}, 800, 'easeInExpo');
    });
```

I am new to jQuery and I have a problem that I am unable to solve:
I want to expand a vertical menu. The code that expands the menu works fine, but after the menu is expanded (the classes change), jQuery is unable to select `$('div.expanded')`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try binding a `live` event. such as `$('div.minimized').live("click", function(e){});` and `$('div.expanded').live("click", function(e){});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the old way of attaching event handlers, which relies on the element existing when the handler is set up. Change your .click() to .on('click') and it will fix the problem.

[jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Simply changing `click` to `.on('click')` does not solve the problem. Both are equivalent.

Comment: @FelixKling how do you figure? The element with class 'minimized' does not exist at the time the handlers are bound. Using on fixes this.

Comment: No it does not. As I said, `.click()` and `.on('click')` are both doing the exact same thing. You have to pass a third parameter, a selector, if you want to use `.on` for event delegation.

Comment: @FelixKling you are correct, i assumed that would go without saying, otherwise there is no reason to use .on or .delegate

Answer (score 3):

At the time you try to bind the event handler to `div.expanded`, the element does not exist yet<sup>*</sup>. Hence jQuery cannot find it and bind the handler.

You can solve this problem using [*event delegation*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/):

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'div.minimized', function() {
   //...
});

$(document.body).on('click', 'div.expanded', function() {
   //...
});
```

Instead of binding an event to each element that matches the selector, a handler is bound to the selected elements (`$(document.body)`) and triggered whenever the event occurs on an descendant which matches the selector (`div.expanded`). You should choose the first selector as close as possible to the actual elements you want to trigger the event for.

More information can also be found in [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) under *Direct and delegated events*.

---

*: To be more precise, the element actually does exist, but it does not have the class `expanded` yet, so it is not matched by this selector.

Comment: +1. Minor nitpick: `document.body` in `$(document.body)` is not a _selector_, but a DOM element.

Comment: @Mathias: Right, I wanted to use it as a more general term referring to selected elements, but I phrased it differently now to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method.

```
$("div.expandable").toggle(function() { 
    // expand
}, function() {
    // minimize
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The handlers are bound at the time of execution of the code you have given. You need to bind one click handler and check the element state (e.g. the presence of the `expanded` class) to choose one of the two branches corresponding to the two handlers above (one to expand, one to collapse.)